# Probability of picking at least one rotten strawberry among five?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question goes like this:

In a box containing $36$ strawberries, $2$ of them are rotten. Kyle randomly picked $5$ of these strawberries.
a. What is the probability of having at least 1 rotten strawberry among the 5?
b. How many strawberries should be picked so that the probability of having exactly $2$ rotten strawberries among them equals $2/35$?

My Work:
a) $C(36,3) = 7140$ and $C(36,5) = 37692$.
$7140 / 37692 = .0189$, which is the probability of having at least $1$ rotten strawberry.  Is this correct? If not, what did I do wrong?
b) I have no clue where to start, any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: why did you compute C(36,3)?

Comment: In part (a), you calculated the probability of obtaining both rotten strawberries when you select five of them.  In order to get the correct answer, you would have to add to that the probability of obtaining exactly one rotten strawberry when you pick five of them.

Comment: This is an example of the hypergeometric distribution.  For part a, you have $X\tilde{ } HG(36,5,\frac{2}{36}$ and need to find $P(X\geq1)$.  For part b, you need to find the value n such that for $X\tilde{ }HG(36,n,\frac{2}{36})$, $P(X=2)=\frac{2}{35}$

Answer (score 1):

It's often easier to approach a problem like this backwards.  Let's compute the probability that you picked no rotten strawberries.

There are $\binom{34}{5}$ ways to choose $5$ good strawberries and $\binom{36}{5}$ ways to choose any $5$ strawberries, so the probability that you choose $5$ good strawberries (after some cancellation) is $\frac{31 \cdot 30}{36 \cdot 35}= \frac{31}{42},$ which means the probability that you choose at least one rotten strawberry is $\frac{11}{42}$.

Picking $n$ strawberries that include $2$ rotten strawberries means that you're picking $n-2$ good ones from among $34$ choices, so the probability that this happens is:

$$\frac{\binom{34}{n-2}}{\binom{36}{n}}.$$

There will be cancellations that make this fraction easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

> In a box containing $36$ strawberries, $2$ of them are rotten.  Kyle randomly picked $5$ of these strawberries.  What is the probability of at least one rotten strawberry among the five?

Your answer is incorrect.  What you have calculated is the probability that both rotten strawberries are among the five.  To obtain the correct answer, you need to add to that the probability that exactly one of the five strawberries Kyle selects is rotten.

The probability that Kyle selects exactly $k$ rotten strawberries among the five he randomly picks is
$$\Pr(\text{exactly $k$ rotten strawberries}) = \frac{\dbinom{2}{k}\dbinom{34}{5 - k}}{\dbinom{36}{5}}$$
since if he picks $k$ of the $2$ rotten strawberries, Kyle must also select $5 - k$ of the $36 - 2 = 34$ good strawberries.  Therefore, the probability that Kyle picks at least one rotten strawberry is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{at least one rotten strawberry}) & = \Pr(\text{exactly one rotten strawberry} + \Pr(\text{exactly two rotten strawberries})\\ 
& = \frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{34}{4}}{\dbinom{36}{5}} + \frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{34}{3}}{\dbinom{36}{5}}
\end{align*}
In any selection, Kyle must pick exactly zero, exactly one, or exactly two rotten strawberries.  Therefore,
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{0}\dbinom{34}{5}}{\dbinom{36}{5}} + \frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{34}{4}}{\dbinom{36}{5}} + \frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{34}{3}}{\dbinom{36}{5}} = 1$$
as you can verify by direct calculation.  Hence, the probability that Kyle selects at least one rotten strawberry can be found by subtracting the probability that Kyle selects no rotten strawberries from $1$, as Robert Shore did in his answer.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{at least one rotten strawberry}) & = 1 - \Pr(\text{no rotten strawberries})\\
& = 1 - \frac{\dbinom{2}{0}\dbinom{34}{5}}{\dbinom{36}{5}}\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{34}{4}}{\dbinom{36}{5}} + \frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{34}{3}}{\dbinom{36}{5}}
\end{align*}
which agrees with the answer we obtained above.

> In a box containing $36$ strawberries, $2$ of them are rotten.  Kyle randomly picked $5$ of these strawberries.  How many rotten strawberries should be picked so that the probability of having exactly two rotten strawberries among them is $2/35$?

The probability of selecting exactly $2$ rotten strawberries among $n$ is
$$\Pr(\text{exactly $2$ rotten strawberries}) = \frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{34}{n - 2}}{\dbinom{36}{n}} = \frac{\dbinom{34}{n - 2}}{\dbinom{36}{n}}$$
Set this quantity equal to $2/35$, simplify, and solve for $n$.